# Reference to non-NULL value NULL after assignment

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I'm implementing a singly linked list using C.

```
struct Node 
{
    int nodeValue;
    struct Node* pNext;
};

struct Node* head;

void createList()
{
    head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
}

void insertNodeAtBeginning(int value)
{
    struct Node* newNode;
    newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->nodeValue = value;
    struct Node* auxNode;

    if(head->pNext == NULL)
    {
        head->pNext = newNode;        
    }

    else
    {
        auxNode = head->pNext;
        head->pNext = newNode;
        newNode->pNext = auxNode;    //breakpoint set here
    }
}
```

I've set a breakpoint on line marked by the comment. The value of auxNode is non-NULL:

```
(gdb) p auxNode
$4 = (struct Node *) 0x5555555551db <createList+18>
```

However the value of newNode->pNext to which the auxNode is assigned is NULL:

```
(gdb) p newNode->pNext
$5 = (struct Node *) 0x0
```

Could anyone clarify this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: The line hasn't executed if you are stopped on that line. `step` to run that line and then examine the values again.

Comment: (a) Edit the question to provide a [mre]. (b) `createList` allocates space for one node and sets `head` to point to it but does not fill in that space, nor does any of the other code shown. `insertNodeAtBeginning` may be using the contents of that space uninitialized. (c) When the code breaks at the line `newNode->pNext = auxNode`, the line has not been executed yet.

Comment: [You should not cast the return value of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2487517)

Comment: `head->pNext` is not initialized in `createList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function `createList` does not make a sense.

```
void createList()
{
    head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
}
```

You already created an empty list

```
struct Node* head;
```

Within the function data members `nodeValue` and `pNext` were not initialized,

The function `insertNodeAtBeginning` also does not make a sense because at least it does not insert a node at beginning due to this code snippet

```
if(head->pNext == NULL)
{
    head->pNext = newNode;        
}
```

Moreover it invokes undefined behavior because the data member `pNext` of the node pointed to by the pointer `head` was not initialized. And again you forgot to initialize the data member `pNext` of the new node when `head->pNext` is equal to `NULL`.

Remove the function `createList` and define the function `insertNodeAtBeginning` the following way

```
int insertNodeAtBeginning(int value)
{
    struct Node* newNode = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = newNode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newNode->nodeValue = value;
        newNode->pNext = head;
        head = newNode;        
    }

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to maintain your head node, but insert between the head node and the node after the head node, correct? If that is the case, then aside from a misleading function name (perhaps insertNodeAfterHead would be more appropriate), you should initialize your head struct members after you allocate with malloc.

Should be...

```
void createList()
{
    head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    head->nodeValue = 0
    head->pNext = NULL;
}
```